# Publish Azure Web Role : package not created

Tags: azure, deployment, powershell-3.0, azure-web-roles, powershell-cmdlet

To create, configure and deploy my Azure Cloud PHP Services, I am using the cmdlets on Windows Azure Powershell.

Via the 'Web platform Installer' tool, I updated the following programs :

- Windows Azure PowerShell - 0.8.8.1
- Microsoft Azure SDK - 2.4.1.0
- Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.4

Since this update, the package creation (local or cloud) and its deployment does not work anymore. I can't update or install new cloud PHP services (web role or worker role)

Here is the main steps, I am using, to create a new PHP Web Role

```
    Select-AzureSubscription XXXX -Verbose
    New-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName ntgTest
    Set-AzureServiceProject -Location "West Europe" -Slot Staging -Storage ntgTestStorage
    Add-AzurePHPWebRole -Name manageTest -I 1 -Verbose
    Set-AzureServiceProjectRole manageTest php 5.4.0
    Set-AzureServiceProjectRole manageTest -VMSize ExtraSmall
    Set-AzureServiceProjectRole manageTest -Instances 1
    Publish-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName ntgTest -Slot Staging -Location "West Europe"
```

I encounter issues and error messages (Sorry, due to my environment, some errors are in French)

1. When I am running the 'Publish-AzureServiceProject' cmdlet to publish my service to the Cloud, the package 'cloud_package.cspkg' is not created.

   > Error Message : Publish-AzureServiceProject : Can not find the file 'C:\WORKSPACES\CLOUD\azure\production\ntgTest\cloud_package.cspkg'
2. The Publish-AzureServiceProject cmdlet indicates the -PackageOnly option to only create the package (Example section :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495166.aspx) This option is not supported !!!

   > Error Message : Publish-AzureServiceProject : Impossible de trouver un paramètre correspondant au nom « PackageOnly ».
3. When I want to launch the emulator via the 'Start-AzureEmulator' cmdlet to test locally my service, the package 'local_package.csx' is not created

   > Error Message : Start-AzureEmulator : An unexpected failure occurred.
   >
   > Details: C:\WORKSPACES\CLOUD\azure\production\ntgTest\ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg: Error CloudService51 : Marque d'ordre d'octet Unicode manquante. Impossible de basculer en Unicode. Error when creating deployment.
   >
   > Exception details: Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabricException:
   >
   > - An error occurred while processing service configuration file: C:\WORKSPACES\CLOUD\azure\production\ntgTest\ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg
   > - to Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabric.ProcessModel(String ucxDir, String cscfg, DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions, ServiceDefinitionModel& sdm, ServiceConfigurationModel& scm, TranslateOptions& transOpts)
   > - to Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabric. CreateSingleInstanceDeployment (String serviceDirectory, String cscfgFile, DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions)
   > - to Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.CloudServiceRun.DoActions.Run(DirectoryInfo dir, FileInfo serviceConfiguration, Boolean launchBrowser, Boolean paused, String debugger, Boolean useIISExpress, List`1 portOverrides)
4. The cmdlet New-AzureServiceProject creates the configuration files (ServiceDefinition.csdef and ServiceConfiguration.XXX.cscfg) using the utf-16 encoding :

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`

   - What is wrong when I generate the package (cloud or local) ?
   - Is there any missing or invalid steps ?
   - Can I specify the utf-8 encoding for the configurations files ? (as it seems part of my issues)

Comment: I had to downgrade to [0.8.7.1 version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/releases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update:

Looks like there is an issue posted against it:

*Publish-AzureServiceProject : cloud and local package not created #2926* at github https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/2926

---

My deployment scripts stopped working after I upgraded to Azure cmdlets version 0.8.8.1. The culprit is the New-AzureServiceProject cmdlet. Its now creating initial csdef/cscfg with  at the top like in your case. I will either downgrade Azure cmdlet  to the previous version to fix this temporarily. Thx for the suggestion. But I must find a way to fix this in the long run so I can take advantage of new and enhanced Azure cmdlets.